# Repository of BNF Grammars?

Tags: mysql, objective-c, grammar, bnf

Is there a place I can find Backus–Naur Form or BNF grammars for popular languages?  Whenever I do a search I don't turn up much, but I figure they must be published somewhere.  I'm most interested in seeing one for Objective-C and maybe MySQL.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

you have to search on tools used to create grammars: "lex/yacc grammar", "antlr grammar" "railroad diagram"

http://www.antlr3.org/grammar/list.html

Here's some grammar files

### objective-c

- http://www.omnigroup.com/mailman/archive/macosx-dev/2001-March/022979.html
- http://www.cilinder.be/docs/next/NeXTStep/3.3/nd/Concepts/ObjectiveC/B_Grammar/Grammar.htmld/index.html
- https://github.com/pornel/objc2grammar

### python

- http://www.python.org/dev/summary/2006-04-16_2006-04-30/#the-grammar-file-and-syntaxerrors

### javascript

- http://tomcopeland.blogs.com/EcmaScript.html
- http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/dherman/javascript/

### ruby

- http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/Manual/man-1.4/yacc.html

Answer (score 6):

There are some links from [w:BNF#Language Grammars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus-Naur_form#Language_Grammers).

- [BNF Grammars for SQL-92, SQL-99 and SQL-2003](http://savage.net.au/SQL/index.html)

I also found a [page](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?TheMethodDefinitionAndTheSemicolon) that lists grammars for Objective C.

- [Objective-C grammar for Lex/Yacc Flex/Bison](http://www.wodeveloper.com/omniLists/macosx-dev/2001/March/msg00807.html)
- [Reference Manual for the Objective-C Language](http://objc.toodarkpark.net/grammar.html)

Answer (score 6):

FWIW, the MySQL grammar file (`mysql-server/sql/sql_yacc.y`) is open source and browseable at launchpad.net (though it's a bit slow and I got an error when I tried to pull up the specific file).

Also, a snapshot of the whole MySQL Server source is downloadable from [dev.mysql.com](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.1.html#source).

Comment: The issue with reusing the grammar that is used by the MySQL server is that is depends on the tokens generated by the lexer. The lexer, having ~115 members, is neither easy to use nor easy to replace.

Answer (score 3):

IIRC, BNF grammars are just different enough from what yacc/bison want as input to be really annoying :)  If you intend to feed these files into a parser generator, you may want to look for files in the appropriate format.  I recall seeing such files for Java, JavaScript and C++ at one point.  Probably as part of Eclipse, Firefox and GCC, respectively, but I can't remember for sure.  I would assume you can find pretty much any parser input file by finding an open source project that uses that language.

Answer (score 2):

I also searched this and i collected this repository

http://slps.github.io/zoo/