# ANTLR parser hanging at proxy.handshake call

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr3, parser-generator, ecma262

I am attempting to get a basic ECMAScript parser working, and found a complete ANTLR grammar for [ECMAScript 3](http://research.xebic.com/es3/), which appears to compile ok and produces the appropriate Lexer/Parser/Walker Java files.
(Running inside [ANTLR IDE plugin](http://antlrv3ide.sourceforge.net/) for Eclipse 3.5)

However, when actually trying to use it with some simple test code (following [guide on ANTLR wiki](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=789)), it just hangs when trying to create the parser:

```
CharStream MyChars = new ANTLRFileStream(FileName); // FileName is valid
ES3Lexer MyLexer = new ES3Lexer(MyChars);
CommonTokenStream MyTokens = new CommonTokenStream(MyLexer);
MyTokens.setTokenSource(MyLexer);
ES3Parser MyParser = new ES3Parser( MyTokens ); // hangs here
ES3Parser.program_return MyReturn = MyParser.program();
```

I've tracked down the problem to inside the `ES3Parser` constructor, where it's calling the function `proxy.handshake()` - before this line I can successfully do `System.out.println("text")` but after it I get nothing.

So, how do I go about finding out why it's hanging, and stopping it - or even just bypassing this section (can/should I disable debugging?) - so long as that lets it work and allows me to get on with doing useful stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by disabling the generation of debug code within the ANTLR IDE plugin.

The setting for this is under Windows > Preferences > ANTLR > Code Generation.

Expand the General section and untick the debug option:

[image: https://www.bpsite.net/misc/eclipse-antlr-debug.png]
<sub>(source: [bpsite.net](https://www.bpsite.net/misc/eclipse-antlr-debug.png))</sub>

Answer (score 4):

There is a -debug option in Antlr that causes additional code to generated allowing for remote debugging. When the code pauses on the the

```
dbg.Handshake();
```

call, it is waiting for the remote debugger to connect to it. In AntlrWorks you can use the Run --> Remote Debug option to connect to it and step through the code.

If you don't wish to use the remote debugging functionality, remove the -debug option from the ANTLR options text box.

File --> Preferences --> General --> ANTLR Options