# Parsing JavaScript code in Java to retrieve variables' names

Tags: java, javascript, string, parsing

I have a Java `String` that contains javascript code, and i need to extract all the javascript `var`s' names.

So, for the following javasctipt:

```
var x;
var a,b,c,d;
var y = "wow";
var z = y + 'x';
```

I need to get `"x,a,b,c,d,y,z"` as a result.

I dont need to get their values, just their names.

Comment: Do you mean like reading a file containing javasscript in java?

Comment: I think what you are asking is answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051678/getting-all-variables-in-scope

Comment: so, you have a Java String variable that contains javascript code, and you need to extract the names of all javascript vars?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you can try and get the bindings that the execution of the script creates:

```
ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine se = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");

try {
    se.eval("var x;var a,b,c,d;var y = \"wow\";var z = y+'x';");
    Bindings bindings = se.getBindings(ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);
    System.out.println(bindings.keySet());
}
catch (ScriptException e) {
    //e.printStackTrace();
}
```

this prints `[d, b, c, println, a, context, z, y, print, x]`

as you see some extra bindings are defined: `context, print and println`

and here we filter them out

```
Set<String> keySet = bindings.keySet();
keySet.removeAll(Arrays.asList("context", "print", "println"));
System.out.println(keySet);
```

this prints `[d, b, c, a, z, y, x]`

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following:

```
List<String> vars = new ArrayList<String>();

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^\\s*var\\s+(.*?)\\s*;?$");

BifferedReader reader = .... // create the reader
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
    if (m.find()) {
        vars.addAll(Arrays.asList(m.group(1).split("\\s*,\\s*")));       
    }
}
```

Please note that I wrote this code without IDE and have never compiled and ran it. So, sorry for possible bugs but I thing it is readable enough and can be a good starting point for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this would be too convoluted, but I would probably get the BNF for Javascript (see [SO: Repository of BNF Grammars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334479/repository-of-bnf-grammars)) and then use something like [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) to create a parser for Javascript, which you can then use to extract all the variables based on the Javascript source code.  See also [SO: ANTLR Tutorials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278480/antlr-tutorials).