# How to parse bash in Java

Tags: java, bash, parsing, antlr, grammar

I need to parse Bash in Java and generate an AST. This is do some analysis on imported shell scripts to check for potential issues. The analysis is a bit more involved than can be done with regex.

Research I have already done:

- ANTLR is often great for this, but there isn't an open-source grammar for bash or shell
- The official bash grammar ([parse.y](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/parse.y)) is in yacc which is heavily tied to C
- There are some yacc-like parsers for Java, e.g. JavaCC. However, converting the bash yacc looks like a big job.
- There is a [BNF grammar](https://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/operating-systems-and-server-administration/unix/1565923472/syntax/lbs.appd.div.3) for bash but it's only bash 2.0 and misses many features. There are several BNF parsers for Java, e.g. bullwinkle

At this point I'm pretty stuck. Some ideas I had:

- Update the BNF grammar to support newer bash features
- Find some semi-automated way to convert the yacc grammar to a format that can be used with Java
- Run the yacc parser as native code and interface with JNI

Any further suggestions gratefully received!

Comment: Also, you can try to implement ANTLR grammar by yourself. Writing grammars is not very hard job.

Comment: There is a [java version of gentoo's libbash bashparser](https://github.com/NitorCreations/bashparser). As a usage example I found [crashub bash](https://github.com/crashub/bash/blob/f26985aa5913411c9cff91463147998c8819c8a9/src/main/java/org/crashub/bash/Script.java#L60).

Comment: @Socowi - Nice find, thank-you!

Comment: The yacc file can be used to get a tentative grammar as i said in an answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/55997867/3225638
I'm not sure if you want to keep the logic defined under each production rule but you could always just refer to them any time if you need (although i don't understand them and just wanted the production rules)

Comment: I want to do this too. Some bash script checking (e.g. for valid paths) would go a long way to helping everyone's productivity.

Comment: I just added a wiki page with some sample code: https://github.com/NitorCreations/bashparser/wiki