# Is there a BNF grammar openly available for JavaScript ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, compiler-construction, grammar, bnf

I am working on a merge tool for JavaScript programs, and I need to write a grammar for JavaScript (version >= ES6) in [JavaCC](https://javacc.org/) format.

For that, I want to use an openly available BNF grammar for ES6, then I would write the grammar in JavaCC format from it.

I was able to find only those (from this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334479/repository-of-bnf-grammars)):

- http://tomcopeland.blogs.com/EcmaScript.html
- http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/dherman/javascript/

However, these are very old BNFs (and the question on StackOverflow is also very old, from 11 years ago). These grammars work only - and in a limited manner - for versions < ES6.

Do you know about a newer publicly available grammar (BNF, JavaCC file, etc)?

There are parsers available for ES6, such as [Esprima](http://esprima.org/), but, since I have to use JavaCC environment, I need the grammar to work on.

Comment: I'm no language expert, but I don't think ES6 can be expressed purely in terms of a BNF grammar.

Comment: It may be an EBNF

Comment: You may have better luck asking on esdiscuss.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, @torazaburo!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The fully-approved latest version of ECMAScript (ES2017 = ES8) is at https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm

The latest draft of the next version (ES2018) is at https://github.com/tc39/ecma262 (source repo) and https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/ (rendered).

All of these are openly available and contain a grammar for the language. The grammar notation is mostly BNF with some extensions.

Comment: Nice reference! That section (https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-grammar-summary), summarising the grammar, is basically an EBNF, which might suit well to my needs! I will work on it. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: This comment should be the accepted answer!

Comment: Is there a grammar file available that isn't HTML? Something that can be passed to tooling?

Answer (score 8):

## ANTLR

Take a look at the [JavaScript grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/javascript/javascript) from the [ANTLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANTLR) grammars repository.